# Custom protocol support

Tags: gatling

I am not finding documentation for custom protocol support. 
From what I understand, Gatling has core engine that does scheduling, thread management etc, and protocol support is designed as an Actor ?

I am trying to develop a custom protocol (thats basically a shell script that will talk to an external service). The latest reference documentation does not seem to have any reference to how to do this ? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of protocol? Are you interested in writing support for a new request Protocol, Reporting (to something other than graphite), or something else?

Comment: Am interested in calling a shell script that will call a third party external service. I like the gatling engine and so want to re-use and just use the custom protocol support to call a shell script instead. Is this feasible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to stress test something that is implemented in a shell script, then Gatling probably isn't the best fit. Gatling is designed for stress testing networking protocols. So unless you can duplicate what your shell script is doing in Gatling expressed in networking protocols, you then might want to use something else.

Secondly, if you did implement it, I would check with the core developers of Gatling if it's something that they would consider including (use a github issue to ask). Since the applications of this might not be widespread, they may choose to not include it in their project. If that's the case you would have to either run your own fork with the implementation or add some sort of plugin architecture to Gatling for 3rd part extensibility.

So my suggestions are:

- Decompose your shell script into the specific network protocol parts you're interested in stress testing implementing in Gatling.
- Use a different tool that's designed to running multiple shell scripts at once for stress testings. Something like GNU Parallel if you're on a Linux box.
- Implement it yourself. There's no documentation on how to do this. However a good starting example would be the [JMS Protocol Implementation](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/tree/master/gatling-jms/src) to give you an idea of all that's involved.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My shell script indeed is making network calls. I will try and check JMS Protocol implementation and see if I can break the shell script down.